# What do the MouseThreshold1 and MouseThreshold2 do in the Windows Registry

Tags: windows-registry

What do the MouseThreshold1 and MouseThreshold2 do in the Windows?

It's in Registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`. There is nothing in *help* and I found no info otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mouse movement speed exceeds the value in `MouseThreshold1`, cursor speed is doubled.

If mouse movement speed exceeds the value in `MouseThreshold2`, cursor speed is quadrupled.

Comment: Only if "Enhance pointer precision" (mouse acceleration) is enabled in Mouse Properties > Pointer Options